# How can I sort a dataframe on a row rather than a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
    Albania Andorra Armenia Austria Azerbaijan
2014    98.0    96.0    97.0    96.0    98.0
2013    99.0    95.0    97.0    96.0    98.0
2012    98.0    98.0    97.0    95.5    97.0
2011    99.0    99.0    97.0    96.0    98.0
2010    99.0    99.0    97.0    96.0    98.0
```

and I would like to sort the columns on the `2014` row.  So the resulting sort should have the columns as Albania, Azerbajain, Armenia, Andorra, Austria.

I bet I could do it using `df.values` and then sorting the resulting ndarray, but could `df.sort_values` do this?  I tried `df.sort_values('2014',axis = 1)` but got the error `KeyError: '2014'`.

closest I can get without using arrays is `f[f.ix['2014'].sort_values(ascending = False).index]`

Comment: `2014` is an integer, not a string

Comment: Tried that as well, still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Take transpose then sort

```
df.T.sort_values(2014).T
```